# Android ICS - Show the CA certificate installation prompt only if it is not already present

Tags: android

I have developed an android application which need secure communication with the server. I get exception about untrusted server because my server's certificate is not part of android's cert list.

I make use of following KeyChain APIs (available from ICS onwards) to prompt user for the certificate installation, after which the communication works seamlessly.

```
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(getAssets().open(
                PKCS12_FILENAME));
        byte[] keychain = new byte[bis.available()];
        bis.read(keychain);

        Intent installIntent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
        installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_PKCS12, keychain);
        installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, DEFAULT_ALIAS);
        startActivityForResult(installIntent, INSTALL_KEYCHAIN_CODE);
```

I am using the above code on the application startup and it prompts even when the certificate is already present. With regards to this, I have following two questions,

1. Programmatically how do I identify whether a particular certificate is already present or not? So that I prompt only when it is not already present.
2. Is there any event which occur during application installation, that I should use to prompt user for the certificate installation?

Comment: There was a similar question here a few days ago, not sure whether it was answered. Is it possible to simply *attempt* communication and intercept the security exception for the missing cert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to enumerate trusted certificates. If the alias starts with 'user' it is user-installed. This is not part of the public API though, so it might break on future versions. More details here: http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/ics-trust-store-implementation.html

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
ks.load(null, null);
Enumeration aliases = ks.aliases();
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = aliases.nextElement();
    X09Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) 
       ks.getCertificate(alias);
    Log.d(TAG, "Subject DN: " + 
       cert.getSubjectDN().getName());
    Log.d(TAG, "Issuer DN: " + 
       cert.getIssuerDN().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since seems that [it is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124631/how-i-get-a-certificate-list-installed-in-android-4-0) to retrieve a list of installed certificates programmatically, you can't say when your certificate is already installed. IMHO you should install it if you get the exception about untrusted server.

Also there is not an event occouring during application installation (also who should catch such event?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With event I meant is there any life cycle method which I should override to take these kind of decisions.

Comment: Suppose I install the certificate only when I get the exception, then, do we have a way to know from the exception that which certificate I should install?

Comment: If you want to intercept the installation process, the application that you are installing can't receive the signal.

Comment: if you get the exception during the communication and the exception is certificate related, you know that you don't have that certificate, isnt?

Comment: The user of my application may decide which server he want to connect. And the new server might be using different certificate. So when the exception occur while communicating to new server, proposing the old certificate install would not help! I can get the certificates of all servers, but the question is, is there a way to know from the exception that which certificate could fix this problem?